# How to call a function a certain time after a web service has been called?

Tags: php

How to call a function a certain time after a web service has been called?

I need to check if a request has been accepted 30s after the request has been created, something like that:

```
public function create_request(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->id;

    $validator = Validator::make(
        $request->all(),
        array(
            'request_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:requests,id,user_id,' . $user_id,
        ));

    // Create Request
    $requests = new Requests;
    $requests->user_id = $user_id;

    if ($request->service_type)
        $requests->request_type = $request->service_type;

    $requests->status = REQUEST_NEW;
    $requests->confirmed_provider = $request->provider_id;
    $requests->request_start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $requests->s_address = $request->s_address ? $request->s_address : "";

    if ($request->s_latitude) {
        $requests->s_latitude = $request->s_latitude;
    }
    if ($request->s_longitude) {
        $requests->s_longitude = $request->s_longitude;
    }

    $requests->save();

    sleep(30);

    $request = Requests::where('id', '=', $request->request_id)->first();

    if ($request['provider_status'] == 0) {
        Requests::where('id', '=', $request['id'])->delete();
        $response_array = array('success' => true , 'message' => Helper::get_message(121));
    } else {
        $response_array = array('success' => false, 'error' => Helper::get_error_message(161), 'error_code' => 132);
    }

    return response()->json($response_array, 200);

}
```

The problem with this approach is that the sleep function (`sleep(30);`) is causing the web service response (`return response()->json($response_array, 200);`) to be delayed too.

I was expecting something similar to `setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 30000);` in Javascript

Comment: create a separate non-blocking process to check if `$requests->save();` was done I assume this saves something to persistent storage ( such as a DB ), on linux you can run it with `exec({path to php} {path to script} > /dev/null &)`

Comment: Why 30 seconds? You either have a very quick human processing requests or a very slow computer. If original submission is via ajax then have a success function which tells client the request is being processed output to client where you currently sleep and a 30 second setTimeout to perform a second ajax call to a script containing everything after the sleep line to get confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable at start with value "set" or something.

from start of function down to sleep(30) have a `if(variable == "set")`

Then at the point you have sleep(30), replace with `else` that way it will not check if it's set.
Then use meta header to reload the page after 30 seconds, if the session variable is "set" change it to "check".

This way first time it will set, then next time it will check.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate background process to check if `$requests->save()` was done for the request.

Because it's a separate process you have to save something in persistant storage like a database, and have a way to identify it.

You would run the script like this

```
  exec('php script.php arg1 > /dev/null &')
```

This will run `script.php` non-blocking, which means the current script will continue on without waiting for response from `exec`. `arg1` will show up in the `$_SERVER` array as `argv` with the first argument being the name of the running script.

In that script you would delay for 30's then do your check.

No problem.

Windows is a bit more complicated for a non-blocking script. But it can be done using `wScript.Shell`

```
$wShell = new \COM('WScript.Shell');
$cmd = 'cmd /C php script.php arg1';
$oExec = $wShell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```